# Enable serial ports on Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox, serial-port

I am using Windows 10 and Virtual Box. I am loading MSDOS. I am trying to add serial ports on VB. The instructions I have read say to click Serial Ports then Enable Serial Port. But that is grey. I am using the tab called Port 1 (which is not grey).

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Do it when the Virtual Machine is turned off?

Answer (score -2):

Did you try to enable it when the Virtual machine is turned on? or Off?

You can't edit most of running Virtual machine settings.

Try turning off the Virtual Machine, and then edit the settings.

Comment: I was doing it when it was being created as instructed by the instructions I found on the internet here: http://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Install-DOS-622-Under-VirtualBox/?ALLSTEPS

Comment: That is not much help. It does not bring up serial ports. Note that I use XP for the guest. XP has an MSDOS emulator. That should not hurt anything.
Since the 1st two ports work just fine.

My program addresses the ports as an 16550 directly.